# Can the iOS Dropbox app download all contents of all folders to my iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios, dropbox

Is it possible to force Dropbox on iPad to sync *all* files?

(That is, to make it working it the same way as it does on a laptop/computer.)

As far as I see, it saves only *files* marked as "Favorite". Adding everything manually does not seem convenient...

Answer (score 3):

Not really. It isn't designed to store everything, but does try to cache files you have downloaded and save them as long as the iOS device doesn't run low on space and tell apps to throw away files that can be re-downloaded.

Keeping more than a Gigabyte of free space on the filesystem will keep iOS from purging the files dropbox has downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with the Dropbox app on iOS. A good alternative would be GoodReader which allows to sync Dropbox folders.

Comment: A problem I have with Goodreader is it recompressing or resizing images imported from the Camera roll.

Comment: And Goodreader is so slooowww! Scrolling through images takes forever...

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled upon this thread while looking for a real sync with DropBox.
Currently there's a free Documents app to do this:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-5-fast-pdf-reader/id364901807?mt=8